# How to add constraint that check values from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column "Date" in table A, columns "Starting date" and "Deadline" in table B.
How can i make a constraint to check values of "Date" in table A (between "Starting date" and "Deadline") ?
I am using SQL server 2014.
Thanks for your help :D

Comment: can you explain it :D

Comment: Create a `before update or insert` trigger and verify the contents. If not valid, raise error using `RAISERROR`

Answer (score 0):

Trigger should only be used as a last option. I will prefer using check constraint in this case. First create a function that will return 0 or 1 by checking value of passed date in tableB.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[checkDate]
    (@dt datetime)
RETURNS bit
AS

BEGIN

IF EXISTS
            (
                SELECT * 
                FROM TableB
                WHERE checkDate is between [Starting Date] and [Deadline]
            )
            RETURN 1
    RETURN 0
END
```

Then add this function to TableA check constaint

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableA]  
WITH NOCHECK ADD CHECK  (([dbo].[checkDate]([Date1])=(0)))
```